# Technical reasons behind using Arrays.deepHashCode() when calculating hashcode for multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, hashcode

I have read that to calculate the hashcode for multidimensional array, one has to use `Arrays.deepHashCode()` method instead of `Arrays.hashCode()` method, but I don't really understand the technical reason behind it. Could someone please explain it to me?

```
    Object[][] one = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {11, 22, 33}
    };
    int two = Arrays.deepHashCode(one);
    int three = Arrays.hashCode(one);
    System.out.println("two " + two);
    System.out.println("three " + three);
```

Result:

```
two 997365
three 312355675
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technical reason is that if you simply you call `hashCode()` on the array, you will get an "identity" hashcode; i.e. a hashcode that ignores the values stored in the array.  Thus

```
Object[][] one = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {11, 22, 33}
};

Object[][] won = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {11, 22, 33}
};

println(won.hashCode() == one.hashCode());
```

will print `false`.  In typical cases, you would want hash codes for `one` and `won` to be equal.  To get that, you need the hash code calculation to include the values of all of the array's elements.